# 2 funções no javascript na mesma div

Tags: javascript, html, animação, funções

Tenho divs no meu código em html (são 3 barras de menu), quando eu clico, ela se transforma (como se fosse uma animação) em um x, porém, quero que quando ela se transforme e eu clique nela ela execute outra função diferente da primeira. Um "openNav()" na primeira e um "closeNav()" na segunda, alguem sabe um jeito? Usando o "onClick="

```
  function openNav() {
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
document.getElementById("t").onClick="closeNav()";

 }

 function closeNav() {
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
 }

 function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
 }



      <div id="t" class="container1" onclick="openNav()">
        <div class="container1" onclick="myFunction(this)" >
          <div class="bar1"></div>
          <div class="bar2"></div>
          <div class="bar3"></div>
      </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode ser facilmente resolvido definindo uma variavel global.

```
<script>
var open = true;

  function openNav() {
     document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
     document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
 }

 function closeNav() {
   document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
   document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
 }

 function myFunction(x) {
   x.classList.toggle("change");
   if(open){
     openNav();
     open = false;
   }else{
      closeNav();
      open = true;
   }
 }
</script>
```

Exemplo da Lógica: https://jsfiddle.net/u4rqyfxz/

Comment: Ele da esse erro "Uncaught TypeError: openNav is not a function" apesar de estar logo antes

Comment: @PedroFreitas Acho que por causa da variavel e a function ter o mesmo nome. Alterei e exemplifiquei com um exemplo.

Comment: Valeu! era isso mesmo, muito obrigado

Comment: Variáveis globais são uma péssima solução. Use de atributos do elemento para fazer a manipulação ou encapsule isso em uma `IIFE`. Uma solução sem variáveis globais: https://jsfiddle.net/u4rqyfxz/1/